# Sudden strange keyboard behaviour Mac OS X

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, keyboard

Suddenly my keyboard is behaving weirdly. Here's some examples of what happening:

- Left command not working at all
- Left option + L moves the cursor down one line
- Left control + L moves cursor down one line
- Left X working sporadically
- Left X working sporadically
- Option + T does what Option + Control + T should do
- Control + T does what Option + Control + T should do

So the problem seems to be concentrated around the bottom left area of the keyboard.

Just before this started happening, I cleaned my keyboard with a damp cloth and also repaired computer's disk using Disk Utility. So I assume one of these things is responsible for issues.

Can anyone suggest a fix?

Comment: try another keyboard.  if it works ok, then most likely the original one is damaged.

Comment: is it your built-in keyboard that's the problem? Definitely not the disk repair, very likely water damage. Plenty of suggestions/tales of woe if you google `macbook keyboard water damage`.

Comment: I don't know if you wrote _"Left X working sporadically"_ by mistake or it's part of your keyboards strange behaviour. :P Does this also happen when you try it in a new user account?

Comment: @user14492 did you also notice it was there twice? :)

Comment: @CupawnTae Right, that's what I was trying to write, I guess my keyboard is broken too. :P

Comment: @user14492 oh, I assumed you meant the other aspect - what's a "left X"? Is there a "right X"? :-)

Comment: Took it to Apple store, it's water damaged. I've split coffee on it before and it's been fine. Not sure why a damp cloth has caused water damage.